# DatePicker expands when date is selected / on view load

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using `DatePicker`, and for some reason, it expands when I select a date. Why is this, and how can I prevent it?

Nothing else is affecting the frame size — however, if I delete the rest of the view ( or place the `DatePicker` in a large frame), it still expands, but on view load — it doesn't wait until a date is selected.

Please see this video for a demo: https://www.veed.io/view/407a426b-2fc7-49eb-81b6-07538ae8c818?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

```swift
DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .accentColor(Color.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, opacity: 0.8))
    .colorScheme(.dark)
    .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. it must be something else in your code ...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651023

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add constraints to the DatePicker ?

You could try to add:

```
let exampleDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
exampleDatePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```